# Error: verifier._reset is not a function. when trying to Sign in with phone using firebase, react native and Expo

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to implement Phone Sign In in mu react native app, but I am getting the following error:

```
verifier._reset is not a function. (In 'verifier._reset()', 'verifier._reset' is undefined)
at http://192.168.1.2:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:126633:27 in <unknown>
at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:60:8 in createExporter
at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:18:0 in <global>
at http://192.168.1.2:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:116838:35 in rejected
```

This is how I have tried to implement the signing:

```
const SignUp = () => {
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("")
    const recaptchaVerifier = React.useRef(null);
    const auth = getAuth(app)

    const sendCode = async () => {
        console.log(recaptchaVerifier.current)
        signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current!)
            .then(r => {
            console.log("Hej!")
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView
        style={tw.style('w-full')}>
            <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
                ref={recaptchaVerifier}
                firebaseConfig={app.options}
                attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={tw.style('w-1/2', 'shadow', 'border', 'rounded', 'py-2', 'px-3', 'text-gray-700')}
                onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
                keyboardType="phone-pad"
            />
           <Button title={"Send Code"} onPress={sendCode}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )

}

export default SignUp
```

I have also tried to implement it like this:
`const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth) const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current!)`
but I get the same result.

I am all out of ideas, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Am also facing the same issue,  is the issue resolved if so may i know what's the approach you followed

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest version of `expo-firebase-recaptcha` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file:
`node_modules\expo-firebase-recaptcha\build\FirebaseRecaptchaVerifier.js`
And add

```
export default class FirebaseRecaptchaVerifier {
    token;
    constructor(token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    get type() {
        return 'recaptcha';
    }
    async verify() {
        return this.token;
    }
    async _reset(){
    }
}
```

add the _reset() function there and save it! the error will be fixed.

Comment: Added the same as u mentioned but still am seeing the same error 

code in that file is as below
`export default class FirebaseRecaptchaVerifier {
    token;
    constructor(token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    get type() {
        return 'recaptcha';
    }
    async verify() {
        return this.token;
    }
    async _reset(){
    }
}`

did i miss any thing ?

Comment: Jeff's answer fixed it. I didn't notice that the OP was using FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal. If you're using the Modal you need to add the _reset function in the FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal.js

Answer (score 0):

This answer is close, but even after patching the package I had the same problem.  This appears to be a recent issue, and the OP is using the Modal form, not the raw verifier.

Instead, add the following to node_modules/expo-firebase-recaptcha/build/FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal.js around line 31:

```
    async _reset() {
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your expo package, it has been resolve. (see [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/15102))

Comment: Giving a link to other sites is a good idea, but an anwser should be useful and clear without following link. Consider adding few details or quotes.