# Expo react-native app with firebase phone authentication works on web, error on ios simulator and crashes with no warning on Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I am building a react-native app with expo, I have only 2 components, WelcomeScreen and PhoneLoginScreen. I am trying to implement firebase phone authentication which works fine on the Web but on iOS Simulator I get an error `Verifier._reset is not a function. (In 'verifier._reset()', 'verifiier._reset' is undefined` and on Android, it just crashes when I click the continue button that navigates to the PhoneLoginScreen component. Codes below:

App.js

```
import React from "react"

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"

import WelcomeScreen from "./components/WelcomeScreen"
import PhoneLoginScreen from "./components/auth/PhoneLoginScreen"

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome">
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Welcome"
                    component={WelcomeScreen}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="PhoneLogin"
                    component={PhoneLoginScreen}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

WelcomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Text, View, Button } from "react-native"

export default function WelcomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text>Welcome</Text>
            <Button
                title="Continue"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("PhoneLogin")}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

PhoneLoginScreen.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { firebaseApp, auth } from "../../firebase"
import {
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Button,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native"

import {
    FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal,
    FirebaseRecaptchaBanner,
} from "expo-firebase-recaptcha"

import { PhoneAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth"

export default function PhoneLoginScreen() {
    const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null)
    const [message, showMessage] = useState()
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState()
    const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState()
    const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState()

    const firebaseConfig = firebaseApp ? firebaseApp.options : undefined
    const attemptInvisibleVerification = true

    return (
        <View style={styles.center}>
            <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
                ref={recaptchaVerifier}
                firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
                attemptInvisibleVerification={attemptInvisibleVerification}
            />

            <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter phone number</Text>

            <TextInput
                style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
                placeholder="+1 999 999 9999"
                autoFocus
                autoCompleteType="tel"
                keyboardType="phone-pad"
                textContentType="telephoneNumber"
                onChangeText={phoneNumber => setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
            />

            <Button
                title="Send Verification Code"
                disabled={!phoneNumber}
                onPress={async () => {
                    try {
                        const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth)
                        const verificationId =
                            await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                                phoneNumber,
                                recaptchaVerifier.current
                            )
                        setVerificationId(verificationId)
                        showMessage({
                            text: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
                        })
                    } catch (err) {
                        showMessage({
                            text: `Error 111: ${err.message}`,
                            color: "red",
                        })
                    }
                }}
            />
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter Verification code</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
                editable={!!verificationId}
                placeholder="123456"
                onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
            />
            <Button
                title="Confirm Verification Code"
                disabled={!verificationId}
                onPress={async () => {
                    try {
                        const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                            verificationId,
                            verificationCode
                        )

                        await signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
                        showMessage({
                            text: "Phone authentication successful ",
                        })
                    } catch (err) {
                        showMessage({
                            text: `Error: ${err.message}`,
                            color: "red",
                        })
                    }
                }}
            />
            {message ? (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[
                        StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
                        {
                            backgroundColor: 0xffffffee,
                            justifyContent: "center",
                        },
                    ]}
                    onPress={() => showMessage(undefined)}>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            color: message.color || "blue",
                            fontSize: 17,
                            textAlign: "center",
                            margin: 20,
                        }}>
                        {message.text}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : undefined}
            {attemptInvisibleVerification && <FirebaseRecaptchaBanner />}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    center: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
})
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    // Config info...
}

let firebaseApp

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
    firebaseApp = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth()

export { auth, firebaseApp }
```

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.13.0"
  }
```

I have googled forever and nothing works. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. The maintainers of "expo-firebase-recaptcha" have yet to publish a fix, so until that day comes, this is how you fix it yourself:

Go to node_modules/expo-firebase-recaptcha, open the `build` folder and find `FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal.js`.

Inside of FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal, add the following function to the component definition:

`_reset = () => {}`

I've included a snippet of the file after adding the empty function definition:

`FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal.js`

```
[...]
            else {
                this.setState({
                    visible: true,
                    visibleLoaded: false,
                    resolve,
                    reject,
                });
            }
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Add the following line anywhere inside of the FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal component.
     */
    _reset = () => {}

    onVisibleLoad = () => {
        this.setState({
            visibleLoaded: true,
        });
    };
[...]
```

Note: You will have to do this after every yarn/npm installl or change in node_modules until the publishers push an update.

[Error: verifier._reset is not a function. when trying to Sign in with phone using firebase, react native and Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830200/error-verifier-reset-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-sign-in-with-phone-usin)

Comment: Didn't work. Still have the error

Answer (score 1):

**FIX FOR EXPO 45, 46**

After Surfing through the internet for answers, i failed and din't find anything to make it work on Expo 45 and Expo 46, finally took it to my hands because We can't ship an app with manual recaptcha as it is very bad UX. So after trying every possible prop in the FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal, I FINALLY FOUND THE WORKING FIX

By Combining all the fixes and adding one of my own found, I finally can rest in peace as this is now working.

```js
// Declare the Timeout for Initial Page Load Fix
  const [isInit, setisInit] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      setisInit(true)
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      setisInit(false)
    }
  }, [])

return(
<View>
...
        {isInit && (
          <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
            ref={recaptchaVerifier}
            firebaseConfig={app.options}
            androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
            androidLayerType="software"
            attemptInvisibleVerification
          />
        )}
...

      <FirebaseRecaptchaBanner />
</View>
```

This was the magical line

```bash
 androidLayerType="software"
```

I Hope Expo Updates there Documentation and avoid this painful experience for all of us Developers, I mean I literally never have seen an app with manual  Recaptcha until im spamming

Comment: Hi is ```<FirebaseRecaptchaBanner />``` required?

Comment: no it's a separate component

Comment: I mean is it required in order for the verification to work?

Comment: not required totally optional

Comment: Hi again, what about the FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal is it needed? because on the expo website it says it will be depreciated in sdk 48

Comment: that is the recaptcha itself, let's see what comes of expo 48, if invisible recaptcha works properly this time

Comment: on expo sdk 46, it is working as expected with a work around i found online using setTimeout

Comment: yes, this is a really tricky situation it works for some people sometimes, but not everytime, only when i use all these workarounds, then i get a reliable and stable invisible recaptcha verification, i hope they got it all together in expo 47

Comment: Hello again, sometimes when i press the continue button to move to the otp screen `const verificationId = await provider.verifyPhoneNumber(user.mobileNumber,recaptchaVerifier.current);
` does not get called and sometimes it does. Why is it not always working?

Comment: Do you maintain all the states? also by not getting called do you mean this verificationId is not returned , if the provider.verify command doesn't returned anything you are not going to get a verificationId

Comment: provider.verifyphonenumber sometimes returns the verification id and sometimes it doesnt. Thats my question why does it sometime work and sometime not?

Answer (score -1):

[FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal attemptInvisibleVerification Crashes on Android Emulator](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11256) look at this. This is help me so well.

I add :

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal ref={recaptchaVerifierRef}
     firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig} androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
     attemptInvisibleVerification />
```

This line on my FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal this gonna help to my to problem.

Comment: Didn't work. App still crashes

Comment: It used to work for Pre SDK 45. for SDK 45, it only works if attemptInvisibleVerification  is set to false.